# How to launch InstaSafe Agent application with a bash command?

Tags: bash, scripting

I am using Ubuntu Linux 20.04

I am using an application named `InstaSafe Agent` which connects me to a VPN.

App Logo:

[image]

I want to automate this login process.
For that, I am looking for bash command to run this application from terminal.

this is how it looks when I open this application.
[image]

I have tried to find its installation path like this.

Command: `whereis instasafe`

output: `instasafe: /etc/instasafe`

Can Someone let me know how can I run this application using bash command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed InstaSafe using default settings,
you can try this command.

This worked for me.

```bash
/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/instasafe/isaagent-1.0.jar
```